# Reflection fails in signed build Android

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-module

I'm modularising our ongoing project.

Let's say there is an app module.

And 'n' number of other modules. 
These modules implement app module (i.e implementation project(':app_module'))

From app module I need to launch Module 1..n

I've used reflection to get the activity reference in app_module.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setClass(context, Class.forName("com.application.myapp.HelpActivity"))
context.startActivity(intent)
```

So when I run the application it works fine.

But when I generated a **Signed debug build** and I installed it, I got **ClassNotFoundException**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.application.myapp.HelpActivity" on path: DexPathList
```

Any idea what's causing reflection to fail in **Signed debug build** ?

**Note**: Its not a pro-guard issue. I've disabled it and I've checked. Same issue is there.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure it is an obfuscation issue. Please use APK analyzer (in Android Studio) on your your signed APK and check that your class is actually there.

Comment: Hey I analyzed the APK  found that my modules are not there in classes.dex. But I've added that module in pro-guard. And I've enabled multidex as well. Any idea?

Comment: Add the relevant parts of your gradle file and your proguard config to your question.

Comment: Hi David, I got to know the issue. Its because in Manifest of modules  dist:onDemand="true", Thats why module classes were not present in dex file. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. You can create an answer to your own question and accept that answer. It will get the question off the list of unanswered questions and may help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks David. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
The issue was because the module was treated as a dynamic module.

Cause for the issue was `dist:onDemand="true"` in module's manifest.

I set it to false and generated app bundle and installed it through bundletool. It's working fine now.